# Why datarates have no effect on latency and delay in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, channel

I have introduced channel datarate and delay using:

```
gate1<-->{datarate=100Mbps;delay=5us;}<-->gate2
```

But while simulating I found that this datarate and delay does not have any impact on my latency. 
Also the packets get delivered even if I change the datarate to 0 Mbps.

Please explain this and how to actually use this channel.

Comment: The datarate will have an impact on total delay only if a packet has non-zero size. Do you use `setByteLength()` or `setBitLength()` methods in your code?

Comment: Yes i have used byteLength = 256; in .msg file.